# Imprimir estilo bobina no RLReport

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, relatório

Desenvolvi um relatório estilo cupom, onde tenho o cabeçalho e os itens da minha nota.

```
RLReport - PageSetup:
Orientation : poPortrait
PaperHeight : 220
PaperSize   : fpCustom
PaperWidht  : 80
```

No meu RLReport tenho:

```
RLBand1 - BandType : btHeader
RLGroup
   Band2 - BandType : btHeader
   Band3 - BandType : btDetail (meus itens)  
RLBand4 - BandTye : btFooter
```

O problema é que posso ter N itens, se a quantidade de itens passar o tamanho da página os outros itens vão para segunda pagina, se forem para a segunda página vou ter cabeçalho e rodapé imprimindo duas vezes.

Se eu colocar um tamanho no PaperHeight alto, e não tiver tantos itens, vou estar desperdiçando papel.

Tentei utilizar o componente RLDraftFilter setei a opção:

```
EjectMethod : EjLeavePage
```

No preview no momento de escolher a impressora tentei colocar o filter mas nem uma das opções funcionou, simplesmente a impressora não imprimi.

Estou usando a impressora Datamax Oniel RL4.

Alguém já passou por isso?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Quando tive que fazer isso, utilizei [esta dica](https://showdelphi.com.br/impressao-em-bobina-fastreport-com-altura-infinita/). Replicando:

- Primeiramente vá em Configurar Página. (File > Page Settings)
- Selecione a aba Outras Opções (Other Options)
- Agora marque a opção “Altura de página sem fim” (endless page height).

Outro passo importante é alterar uma propriedade do TFrxReport. Em **PrintOptions > PrintMode** deixe com **pmSplit**.

Depois é só você ajustar a largura correta da página.

Pronto, seu relatório está preparado para a impressão em bobina.

Comment: Eu estou usando TRLReport. Naõ encontrei a opção de PrintOptions.

Comment: Desculpe! Essas instruções são para o FastReport. Juro que li frx ao invés de RL rs...
Neste caso, parece que seu código está todo certo! Tem certeza que não é algum problema com a impressora ou drivers?